# Setting field in a different frame from javascript

Tags: javascript

I have some javascript code, and I want to set the value of a field that's in a different frame. The line in my js code to this is:

```
window.frames.header_frame.document.getElementById('sort_key').value = this.id
```

When that line executes, I get an error:

```
window.frames.header_frame is undefined
```

But if I set a breakpoint on that line, and when it's hit access that
element from the js console it works:

```
>>> window.frames.header_frame.document.getElementById('sort_key')

<input id="sort_key" type="hidden" name="sort_key">
```

What am I doing wrong in my script that is preventing me from accessing that field from the script?

In response to a request to see the HTML I will update my question. Not sure exactly how much to show. They are large, so I'm just posting the relevant parts:

Here the main page:

```
<frameset frameborder=1 border=4 rows="170,*">
   <frame name="header_frame" src="tstatsheader.php?session_name=menu14&book=US&product=**&cluster=&idtype=symbol&id=&sort=aimlast desc&num=1000&refresh=0&tz=US%2FEastern&configname=Production">
   <frame src="tstats.php?session_name=menu14&book=US&product=**&cluster=&idtype=symbol&id=&sort=aimlast desc&num=1000&refresh=0&tz=US%2FEastern&configname=Production"name=tstatsdata>
</frameset>
```

Here is the header frame:

```
<body>
<table border=0 width=100% cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0>
<tr><td align=left><a target=_parent href="mainframes.php?&tz=US/Eastern&configname=Production"><img src="images/predco_vs_bbx_3d.gif"></a></td>
<td align=center>Thursday May 8, 2014<br>US/Eastern</td>
<form method="GET" target=_parent action="tstatsframes.php">
<input type="hidden" name="book" value="US">
<input type="hidden" name="configname" value="Production">
<input type="hidden" name="tz" value="US/Eastern">
<input type="hidden" name="session_name" value="menu14">
<input id="sort_key" type="hidden" name="sort_key">
```

And at the top of the second frame I have:

```
<script src="sorttable.js"></script>
```

And then the markup for that frame. When a certain field is clicked on the event handler in the js code is invoked and from there I am wanting to update the sort_key field in the header frame.

Comment: Is the iframe's content from the same origin as your script?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by origin. There is a page that creates a frameset with 2 frames. In the second frame the script is loaded and from that I want to set a field from the first frame.

Comment: It would probably help if you showed the related HTML.

Comment: I've updated my question with some HTML. If this is not enough let me know and tell me specifically what you need to see. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if this is your issue but you might find this informative: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`header_frame` is a frame in the frameset document, not the document you get from `tstats.php`.

You need to go through `parent.frames` instead of hitting `frames` directly.